# Apollo server v3 playground offline

Tags: apollo, apollo-server

I migrated from Apollo server v2 to v3 and I had trouble loading a Graphql playground override for offline usage.
The previous syntax was by filling the "playground" property in the Apollo server constructor but now this property doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking for the new way to load my offline playground I found that there is a plugin called [ApolloServerPluginLandingPageGraphQLPlayground](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/plugin/landing-pages/#graphql-playground-landing-page) in the apollo-server-core package.
This package behaves expects the same params as the old syntax and it worked for me.

Hope it will be helpful for someone.